# OpenGL 3D transparency in voxels

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

(Sorry in advance, I'm not at my computer so I can't provide code)
I have a voxel based game, and I wanted to add in transparent textures, namely glass. I realized that transparent textures would throw things off (looking through other blocks), so I used my shaders to remove any alpha components lower than the alpha value of the glass texture. Currently, the glass has an alpha of 0.26 (coordinates range from 0 - 1), and it works fine. But, if I want to add some transparency to the glass instead of removing all transparency, I run into my old issue where you can see through the blocks behind the glass.

I read in a few places that I would need to sort my geometry from front to back. Does this still pertain to my situation even after using shaders? I use display lists, for each chunk in my world, should I keep two lists, one for opaque blocks and one for transparent? So when I render, I would do one pass and render the opaque lists, and then do another render pass, and render the chunks inversely and render the transparent list?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking through blocks behind transparent geometry means you still have depth checking enabled meaning the blocks behind the glass didn't get rendered.

> I read in a few places that I would need to sort my geometry from
>   front to back. Does this still pertain to my situation even after
>   using shaders?

**yes** you still need to sort, geometry shaders don't solve that issue

however you only need to sort the transparent geometry when you render them after the opaque geometry (after turning on alpha blending)

Comment: That's what I thought. So, just for clarification, I have to literally render my chunks from back to front when rendering transparent textures? And when I am doing that, I need to turn off the depth mask, and then enable it afterwards? Anything else I would need to do?

Comment: Also, do I need to actually sort the individual voxels in a chunk too? So, I sort the voxels in the chunk from front to back, and then sort the chunks in the world front to back?

Comment: you need to sort all primitives otherwise you get odd blending, it only matters when they overlap in the view though, if one chunk is to the left and the other to the right  then it doesn't matter which chunk gets rendered first

Comment: Right, but it doesn't matter if I do sort them front to back correct? Do I need to sort the individual voxels though?

Comment: you only need to disable depth writing (`glDepthMask(false);`) when doing the transparent pass

Comment: I think you managed to confuse me already, sorry. I just sort and disable the depth mask? So every chunk is sorted front to back, and every voxel is sorted in the chunks?

Comment: @opiop65 the important part is that the back-most primitives are rendered first.

Comment: @opiop65 Often times the opaque geometry is sorted closest-to-farthest, so that the first things drawn are the most likely ones to cause later things to be depth-culled.  But for translucent geometry, the world is sorted farthest-to-closest, so that the first things drawn are the farthest away.  This is because the traditional alpha-blending function (`Asrc * Csrc + (1 - Asrc) * Cdest`) is order dependent.  If you use additive blending (`Asrc * Csrc + Cdest`) then it doesn't matter what order you draw the transparent geometry, as long as depth-writing is disabled.

Comment: @bcrist, so if I use additive blending, I won't need to sort anything? Will this give me my desired affect?

Comment: @opiop65 Well, you still should sort the translucent stuff from the opaque so that you only need to call `glDepthMask` once after all the opaque stuff, and once at the end.  Whether or not it looks good depends what aesthetic or level of realism you're going for.  It sounds like you're not going for ultra-realism so I think it'd probably work fine.  In real life, glass is almost entirely transparent.  It does block somewhere between 5-10% of light, but most of what you see as glass is reflections.